# print value from a parent tag xml with minidom python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

i've a very big xml file and i need to know ID value if some tag is more than 2.
xml file is like this :

```
<Users>
    <Calendar ID="text1">
        <Folders>...</Folders>
        <FolderRights/>
        <Event/>
        <EventReminder/>
        <EventContact/>
        <EventRecurrence/>
        <EventException/>
        <ContactItem>
            <COLUMNS>...</COLUMNS>
            <FIELDS>...</FIELDS>
            <FIELDS>...</FIELDS>
            <FIELDS>...</FIELDS>
            <FIELDS>...</FIELDS>
        </ContactItem>
        <ContactLocation>...</ContactLocation>
        <Tags/>
        <TagLinks/>
        <ItemAttr/>
        <ItemAttrData/>
    </Calendar>
    <Calendar ID="text2">
        <Folders>...</Folders>
        <FolderRights/>
        <Event/>
        <EventReminder/>
        <EventContact/>
        <EventRecurrence/>
        <EventException/>
        <ContactItem/>
        <ContactLocation/>
        <Tags/>
        <TagLinks/>
        <ItemAttr/>
        <ItemAttrData/>
    </Calendar>
</Users>
```

and i've to print text inside ID of each Calendar tag if FIELDS inside Contact is more than 2 so i write this code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
xmlFile = open('prova.xml','r')
data = xmlFile.read()
xmlFile.close()
dom = parseString(data)
for contatti in dom.getElementsByTagName('ContactItem'):
    if (len(contatti.getElementsByTagName('FIELDS')) > 2):
        print (contatti.getElementsByTagName('Calendar')[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

but i haven't the ID value.
How can i do this? thanks a lot

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: i want "text" attribute on Calendar tag

Comment: Any particular reason you are using minidom instead of etree or lxml? Can Also what text are we talking about?

Comment: no there is no a particular reason

Comment: So you want `ID="text"` where ContactItem tags have more than two Fields?

Comment: yeah right that's what i try to do

Comment: Can you share a proper sample and I can show you a couple of better ways to do it?

Comment: it' like this http://pastebin.com/1CuydnBT but there are many other of Calendar tags but that's the schema

Comment: Are you open to using lxml or etree?

Comment: yeah it's the same for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lxml it is very simple, find the calendar parent tags that have > 2 contactitem//fields tags using [count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(the_xml)

print(tree.xpath("//calendar[count(./contactitem//fields) > 2]/@id"))
```

Sample run:

```
In [8]: from lxml.html import fromstring

In [9]: tree = fromstring(h)

In [10]: tree.xpath("//calendar[count(./contactitem//fields) > 2]/@id"
   ....: )
Out[10]: ['text1']
```

Or using lxml.etree:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

tree = fromstring(h)

print(tree.xpath("//Calendar[count(./ContactItem//FIELDS) > 2]/@ID"))
```

To read from the file use *parse*:

```
from lxml.html import parse
tree = parse("your.xml")
```

You should generally read from the file and let lxml handle the encoding.

*count* is not supported in xml.etree so to do the same you would use findall:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("Your.xml")
cals = tree.findall(".//Calendar") 
print([c.get("ID") for c in cals if len(c.findall("./ContactItem/FIELDS")) > 2])
```

Comment: but i can use also a file instead declare a string with xml file?

Comment: @tafazzi87m you can and you should, just use parse instead of fromstring, I will add it in a sec

Comment: @tafazzi87, no worries,  you can see using lxml makes it a lot more straightforward and actually works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting the right tag element this is the way to access the ID attribute:

```
for contatti in dom.getElementsByTagName('Users'):
    calendars = contatti.getElementsByTagName('Calendar')
    for calendar in calendars:
         attribute = calendar.attributes.get("ID")
         print attribute.name
         print attribute.value
```

Comment: i've this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "file.py", line 20, in <module>
        attribute = calendar.attributes.get("ID")
    AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'attributes'

Comment: Well, your xml sample doesnt have any ContactItem tag, I will update my answer to show you how this is working with your example

Comment: Have you at least tried my code? is working with your pastebin
ID
text1
ID
text2

Comment: It's an example, the point in StackoverFlow is to teach how to do it, for example teaching him to check the attribute value not just copy pasting without learning anything, ofc he would have to add more logic.

Comment: yeah it's works but i've to implement that print only if FIELDS tag in ContactItem there are twice or more

Comment: It's pretty straightforward from my answer, you can get all the contats with contacts = calendar.getElementsByTagName('ContactItem') and then check the fields length with len(contact.getElementsByTagName('FIELDS')) > 2